# How can I migrate zipped folders located on-premises FTP server to Azure storage?

Tags: azure, migration, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, data-migration

I have a zipped folder which have several sub folders and each sub-folders have many files in it. Some files are binary files, some are csv and some are plain text. My requirement is to copy the zip folder, as it is without unzipping it at the on-premise FTP sever, to Microsoft Azure cloud. And this process is not one time but on a regular basis copy whenever a new zip files comes into FTP server.

Comment: Do you have access to the FTP Server? Can you log into that server? Is it possible to install anything? or You just have access to the FTP?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am admin to that FTP, so I can do anything you asked for.

Comment: Ref this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp, choose the file compression: gzip

Answer (score 1):

Please ref this tutorial: [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp)

For example, my zipped file has sub folders and each sub-folders have different files:
[image]

Using Binary format as Source dataset, choose the Commpression type: ZipDeflate:

Source dataset:

[image]

Sink dataset:
[image]

This can achieve the zipped folder copy.

For you purpose, you want to trigger the pipeline when a new zip file is added to into FTP server. Just For Data Factory, the event trigger doesn't support FTP Server. We can't do that.

I think you could achieve that with a [Logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) through [FTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp): When a file is added or modified (properties only) trigger.

[image]

Pass the new add zip file name as Data Factor pipeline parameter, and run the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this solution is not working.